# Pseudo element not showing background-image

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend, pseudo-element

Why is my background-image inside the pseudo element ::before not showing up? I also tested of replacing the background-image with a background-color and it still doesn't work. This is in SASS format in case some would be wondering of the nested ::before.

```css
.logoframe{
      float: left;
      height: 817px;
      width: 20%;
      position: relative;
      left: -6%;
      transform: skewX(-11deg);
      border: 1px solid #e26f6f;
      &::before{
        content: "";
        background-image: url('/images/theseven/seven_img_old.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: relative;
        height: 817px;
        width: 150px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="logoframe"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the "display" property. display is CSS's most important property for controlling layout. Every element has a default display value depending on what type of element it is. The default for most elements is usually block or inline . A block element is often called a block-level element.

```
   &::before{
        content: "";
        display: block;/*missing prop*/
        background-image: url('/images/theseven/seven_img_old.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: relative;
        height: 817px;
        width: 150px;
    }
```

Comment: Can't believe i missed that! It works fine now. Thank you!

Comment: Or `inline-block`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Sometimes you need to add background-size property too with display: block.

&::before{
        content: "";
        background-image: url('/images/theseven/seven_img_old.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size:100%;
        position: relative;
        height: 817px;
        width: 150px;
        display:block;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should update below css part. if you need background image in center please update background-position.

```css
.logoframe{
      float: left;
      height: 817px;
      width: 20%;
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      transform: skewX(-11deg);
      border: 1px solid #e26f6f;
    }
  .logoframe:before {
        content: "";
        background: url('https://n2.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/a/1/Chromozome_Yamaha_102025_m_1_2x-4ab77.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;/* replace 0 0 to center center */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        background-size:contain;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        height: 817px;
        width: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<div class="logoframe"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but sometimes if you are using the shortcuts for the background property it might not work, but if you use the properties differently I think it might work. I am saying this from experience.

```
.showcase::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(../images/Desert.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

But this one did.

```
.showcase::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(../images/Desert.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```